# How do I replace the value of pin in csv (Using DictWriter)

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, file-io

I have this data and I want to replace the value of the pin with the given input using DictWriter

```
name,place,pin
john,usa,1234
corey,canada,1232
tom,usa,4534
```

```
def get_input(name,pin,place):
    with open("data.csv",'a') as file:
        data = csv.DictWriter(file,fieldnames=["name","place","pin"])
        data.writerow({"name":name,"pin":pin,"place":place})
```

How I'm suppose to replace any value in this csv file

Comment: Can you shed some light on, what you want to replace the "pin" with? is it the value of it or the whole column?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to read the `data.csv`, change one `pin` value and save the data using `csv.DictReader`/`csv.DictWriter`:

```py
import csv

# read the data as list of dicts
with open("data.csv", "r") as f_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
    data = list(reader)

# replace pin '1232' with '9999'
for row in data:
    if row["pin"] == "1232":
        row["pin"] = "9999"

# save the data
with open("output.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=data[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

The `output.csv` becomes:

```
name,place,pin
john,usa,1234
corey,canada,9999
tom,usa,4534
```